# How to prevent MongoDB from removing Journal files?

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a project to track changes to a MongoDB database. I plan to extract the change record from MongoDB journal files. But it seems to be MongoDB journal files are deleted when one issues fsync(lock=True) command.

Is there any way to prevent MongoDB from removing journal files? If no, can I safely create hard links to those journal files? By "safely", I mean to create hard links when journal files are created and before they gets deleted.

Comment: I don't think so. You could have your software pose to MongoDB as a secondary replica-set member. The primary would then feed it all changes.

Comment: I agree. I don't think the journal file is what you want. You should make a service that monitors the oplog.

Comment: Thank you very much, but given oplog is at user-record level, will it be a little slow? Thanks.